# Заимствование rust

Tags: rust

Не понимаю до конца, почему в данном коде string передается функции и больше не действителен, а int продолжает существовать?

```
fn c(str: String) -> usize {
    str.len()
}
fn y(mut t: i32)
{
    t += 2;
}
fn main() {
    let q = 4;
    y(q);
    let str = "p".to_string();
    c(str);
    println!("{}", str);
    print!("{}", q);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что i32 тут является копируемым типом, а String - некопируемым:

```rust
#[derive(PartialOrd, Eq, Ord)] // Нет трейта Copy
#[cfg_attr(not(test), rustc_diagnostic_item = "String")]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
pub struct String {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}
```

Comment: [глава](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) в ЯПR, где всё это описано.